# Set a Value in Verbal using sql

Tags: sql-server, new-operator

I want to set "InOperator" value in a Verbal. This is my select Query.

```
DECLARE @i nvarchar(Max); set @i = '619, 618, 620, 2162, 2173, 3613, 2090';
select *  from tbl_PharmacypurDetail where ItmCode in (CAST(@i as bigint))
```

Result

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. `'619, 618, 620, 2162, 2173, 3613, 2090'` isn't a `int`, it's a `varchar` of numerical characters, whitespace and commas. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: i am using sql server r2. and i want to use these values `IN` operator helping with a variables.

Comment: "server r2"? Do you mean SQL Server 2008 R2 (which is **completely** unsupported)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to *splits a string into rows of substrings, based on a specified separator character.*

```
DECLARE @i nvarchar(Max); set @i = '619, 618, 620, 2162, 2173, 3613, 2090';
select *  from tbl_PharmacypurDetail where ItmCode in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@i, ','))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *split* function :

```
select tp.*
from tbl_PharmacypurDetail tp cross apply
     dbo.splitfn(@i, ',') as t(val)
where t.val = tp.itemcode;
```

If you are working with `SQL Server 2016 or higher` then you can use `STRING_SPLIT`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this instead in case your server doesn't support `STRING_SPLIT`:

```
DECLARE @i nvarchar(Max);
SET @i = '619, 618, 620, 2162, 2173, 3613, 2090';

SELECT * 
FROM tbl_PharmacypurDetail 
WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ItmCode) + ',', ',' + REPLACE(@i, ' ', '') + ',') > 0
```